# Templated template argument name is invalid on the head of the method

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

I have the following example code:

```
template<int Size, template<typename Tin, int S> typename Cin, template<typename Tout, int S> typename Cout>
Cout<Tout, Size> SomeTemplatedMethod(const Cin<Tin, Size> &inputData) /* Here the definition fails on Tout and Tin as unknown. */
{
    Cout<Tout, Size> result; // Here Tout doesnt fail!
    //Whichever we do with inputData and result
    return result;
}
```

The code fails in the header of the method but not in the body!
One way I found to resolve this was by doing this:

```
template<int Size, template<typename, int> typename Cin, template<typename, int> typename Cout, typename Tin, typename Tout>
Cout<Tout, Size> SomeTemplatedMethod(const Cin<Tin, Size> &inputData) /* Here the definition doesn't fail. */
{
    Cout<Tout, Size> result; // Here Tout doesnt fail!
    //Whichever we do with inputData and result
    return result;
}
```

But definitely i would like to use the first way because it feels cleaner...

I am using vc++14. What am I doing wrong?, is it a bug or it is an expected behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour.

From [[basic.scope.el]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.temp#1):

> The declarative region of the name of a template parameter of a
>   *template template-parameter* is the smallest *template-parameter-list* in which the name was introduced.

And, from [[basic.scope.el]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.temp#3):

> The potential scope of a template parameter name begins at its point
>   of declaration and ends at the end of its declarative region.

Thus, the declarative region of e.g. `Tin` in you first example above is the *template-parameter-list* in which it is introduced, and its end of scope is the end of that template parameter list. You could e.g. use `Tin` as `template< template< typename Tin, Tin arg> class Cin, ...`, but you cannot use `Tin` to declare a name beyond its scope.

Finally, note that for C++14 and earlier, `template<...> typename TT>` is not legal, as the template template parameter declaration may only use the `class` keyword and not `typename` (your example should this fail on also this for C++14). Barring compiler extensions, in C++14 you would need to use `template<...> class TT>`. Citing [cppreference/template_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> Unlike type template parameter declaration, template template parameter declaration can only use the keyword class and not typename. *(until C++17)*

Answer (score 1):

> But definitely i would like to use the first way because it feels cleaner...

I know that is cleaner, but definitely doesn't works, because the scope of the declaration of `Tin`, `Tout` and `S` is limited to the declaration of `Cin` and `Cout`. (see the dfri's answer for a better explanation).

So you have to declare `Tin`, `Tout` (as `Size`) in the list of template parameters of `SomeTemplateMethod()`.

Your second version works but isn't optimal.

Observe that you have five template parameters (`Tin`, `Tout`, `Cin`, `Cout` and `Size`) and that only three of them (`Cin`, `Tin` and `Size`) are deducible (from the type of the argument `inputData`).

So **you have to explicit at least two of them**: `Tout` and `Cout`.

If you place `Tout` and `Cout` in third and fifth position, in the list of template parameter, as in your working code, you're obliged to explicit all five template parameter, so you're obliged to call the function as follows

```
MyCin<int, 42> mcin;

auto mcout = SomeTemplatedMethod<42, MyCin, MyCout, int, float>(mcin);
```

I suggest to place the non-deducible template parameters before and the deducibles after, by example (also using `class` instead of `typename` declaring the template-templates parameters; required before C++17)

```
template <typename Tout, template <typename, int> class Cout,
          typename Tin, template <typename, int> class Cin,
          int Size>
Cout<Tout, Size> SomeTemplatedMethod (Cin<Tin, Size> const & inputData)
```

This way you have to explicit only the two non-deducible parameters

```
MyCin<int, 42> mcin;

auto mcout = SomeTemplatedMethod<float, MyCout>(mcin);
```

The following is a full compiling example (but I've changed `int` with `std::size_t` for sizes)

```
#include <array>

template <typename Tout, template <typename, std::size_t> class Cout,
          typename Tin, template <typename, std::size_t> class Cin,
          std::size_t Size>
Cout<Tout, Size> SomeTemplatedMethod (Cin<Tin, Size> const &)
 {
   Cout<Tout, Size> result;
   return result;
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::array<int, 42u> x;

   auto y = SomeTemplatedMethod<float, std::array>(x);

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(y), std::array<float, 42u>>::value,
                  "!" );
 }
```